# Analysing data from summary table on R (interactions)

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, t-test, p-value, descriptive-statistics

If I want to test whether `data[,1]:setB` is equal to 0 or not, do I just use the given t value and p value or do I need to add it with the `data[,1]` values?

Looking at the p value of `data[,1]:setB`, I would reject $H_0$, but if I look at the t value,  I would accept $H_0$.

[image: r summary]

Comment: Why would you reject H0 because of the p-value? The t-value (1.088) is directly related to the p-value (0.3182). Significant p-vales are usually lower than 0.05 or 0.01 or even lower. A 2-sided p-value of 0.05 corresponds to a t-value around 2 (if you have at least 30 data points).

Answer (score 2):

The significance test for the interaction is all provided on the last line of the "Coefficients" section of your output. Your t is well under 2 (which is a rough cut off for significance when you have a large N) and your p-value is well above the alphas that are conventionally used (i.e. it is greater than .1, .05 and .01 which are common cutoffs for significance depending on field of study). The row that is labeled data[,1] provides a test of the simple slope of the data[,1] variable when setB is equal to 0. Here is a plot to illustrate this point:

[image]

The test of the interaction is testing whether the slope of these different lines (which represent the slopes of data[,1] at different values of setB (setB = 10,8,6,4,2,0 from top to bottom) are significantly different from each other. The test on the line labeled data[,1] is testing whether the green line's slope (i.e. the slope when setB = 0) is significantly different from 0 (which it is).